# Connection to the database fails

Tags: php, pdo

I'm  using PDO's as PHP extension. My project works fine in local server, but when I upload it on a live server... it throws a connection error..

Here goes my connection.php file

```
<?php

try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cms','root','');
}
catch(PDOException $e) {

    exit('Database Error');
}
?>
```

Comment: if you upload it on live server you need to change `$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cms','root','');` to your `host url` not a `localhost`

Comment: Use `$e->getMessage()` or remove the whole `catch` block to see a detailed error message. This tells you nothing.

Comment: Check your database configuration on server. Does it have password for user 'root'.

Comment: @jeroen getMessage() returns nothing... brother,

Answer (score 0):

Check if the MySQL database ist hosted on the same server as the script is. Otherwise you cannot use localhost.
In addition you may add a password for the root user, which you should have configured already.

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cms', 'root', 'yourpwhere');
```